# runtime error with fragment activity

Tags: android, runtimeexception

I am trying to recreate the [FragmentPagerSupport](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/Support4Demos/src/com/example/android/supportv4/app/FragmentPagerSupport.html) example but I keep getting an error and I dont know what its asking for.

it does this

```
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_pager_list, container, false);
        View tv = v.findViewById(R.id.text);
        ((TextView)tv).setText("Fragment #" + mNum);
        return v;
    }
```

then it throws the runtime error

this is me fragment_pager_list

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
android:id="@+id/layout">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/text"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="60dp"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />



<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/text"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" >

</ListView>

</RelativeLayout>
```

and this is my main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/pager"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

error

```
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074): java.lang.RuntimeException: Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.ensureList(ListFragment.java:344)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.support.v4.app.ListFragment.onViewCreated(ListFragment.java:145)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:858)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1053)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:622)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1371)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executePendingTransactions(FragmentManager.java:429)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter.finishUpdate(FragmentPagerAdapter.java:104)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.populate(ViewPager.java:692)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.support.v4.view.ViewPager.onMeasure(ViewPager.java:851)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8330)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1017)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:386)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8330)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8330)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:531)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:309)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8330)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:3138)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:250)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.view.View.measure(View.java:8330)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:839)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1860)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3839)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:841)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:599)
10-25 18:46:02.514: E/AndroidRuntime(7074):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace the `android:id="@+id/list"` with `android:id="@android:id/list"`